# Segueing to the Maps App in Swift

Tags: swift, mapkit, nsuserdefaults

Hi I am trying to make a button that when pressed takes a location from the NSUserDefaults and goes to the Maps App allowing the user to get directions from their location.  For some reason I am getting an error in my code that says

> "CLLocationCoordinate2D does not have a member named 'mapItem'"

Here is my code

```
@IBAction func DirectionsButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let spotTitle = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("SpotTitle") as! String
    let spotLoc = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("SpotLoc") as! [String : NSNumber]
    //Get user location from that Dictionary
    let spotLat = spotLoc["lat"] as! CLLocationDegrees //Convert NSNumber to CLLocationDegrees
    let spotLng = spotLoc["lng"] as! CLLocationDegrees  //Convert NSNumber to CLLocationDegrees


    let SpotLoca = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(spotLat, spotLng);
    func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {
        let addressDictionary = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): spotTitle]
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: SpotLoca, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)

        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = title

        return mapItem
    }
    let location = SpotLoca
    let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
    location.mapItem().openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
}
```

Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let SpotLoca = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(spotLat, spotLng);
...
let location = SpotLoca
...
location.mapItem().openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

You're dereferencing CLLocationCoordinate2D, which indeed does not have a member mapItem. I think your last line should be:

```
mapItem().openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

Or, you could get rid of the function and just do it like so:

```
let spotTitle = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("SpotTitle") as! String
let spotLoc = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("SpotLoc") as! [String : NSNumber]
//Get user location from that Dictionary
let spotLat = spotLoc["lat"] as! CLLocationDegrees //Convert NSNumber to CLLocationDegrees
let spotLng = spotLoc["lng"] as! CLLocationDegrees  //Convert NSNumber to CLLocationDegrees


let SpotLoca = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(spotLat, spotLng);
let addressDictionary = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): spotTitle]
let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: SpotLoca, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)

let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
mapItem.name = title

let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```